# CIFS Share Mount Error

Tags: mount, samba, cifs, fedora-13

I have a samba share on my Fedora 13 machine. The problem is that on my system if I try to mount the share it failed every time, on all other windows and Linux machines there is no problem.

I used the following command to mount the share:

> mount -t cifs //192.168.1.200/myconfig
>   /tmp/ -o guest

share configurations in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` are:

```
[myconfig]
 comment = Configuration Files
 path = /var/lib/config
 browseable = yes
 guest ok = yes
 writable = no
 printable = no
```

security level in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` is:

```
security = share
```

error returned by mount command is:

```
mount error(110): Connection timed out

Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

kernel log message is:

```
kernel: CIFS VFS: Error connecting to
socket. Aborting operation

kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed
w/return code = -110
```

what is the issue?

Any idea/suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

> Connection timed out

means that connection to the CIFS service on `192.168.1.200` failed.

Make sure that you have `smbd` running, and that it is listening for TCP port `445` on the apropriate interfaces (use `netstat -ltn | grep :445`).

Comment: mount -t cifs //192.168.1.200/myconfig /tmp/ -o guest works perfectly on all other linux and windows systems except on the system( 192.168.1.200) which contains the shared folder

Comment: True, on lots of machines, the smb.conf is present, yet samba itself is not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `hosts allow` line in smb.conf that allows a local connection as well as a LAN one - eg:

```
hosts allow = 127. 192.168.1.
```

Comment: no

Comment: Ok, try adding one either in the global section (mine's below the 'workgroup = ' line) or as part of your [myconfig] definition block